# Connecting ON/OFF switch

Tags: led, switches, ac

Forgive me for the simplicity of this question but I am a microelectronics/very low voltage guy, and I have only 1 switch so I want to get it right the first time. Better safe than sorry :)

I have an ON/OFF switch. It is switches a 230VAC line from a wall outlet  on or off.

[image]

It has a LED to show it is ON, but I am not sure how to connect this. Now the Live line from the power connector is connected to B and via A to the circuit. If i want to use the LED, dow i have to connect C to neutral? I measured the resistor, which is 2,6k Ohm.

Comment: The light is supposed to be a neon indicator if I researched it correctly. http://www.sci.com.tw/PRODUCTS/switch/swit-rocker.htm This is the website of the manufacturer, I have the R13-66B2 switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that is a LED. I've seen similar switches with a small incandescent bulb in series with a 100-150 k resistor.

Yes, 3 should be connected to the neutral wire. If you swap 1 and 2 you will get an always-on light.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAsdGU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I think you are right about the light being a small bulb. The website states it is suited for 250V AC, and there are no other connection to power the light off another voltage or something.

Comment: I believe it is a switch with a neon indicator. This would mean it is safe to connect pin C to neutral, right?

Comment: C pin must connect to the wire that doesn't go through the switch. If you connect live to A, then C goes to neutral.

Comment: @Matthijs you provided a wrong schematic. See my answer now.